Add shortcode below short description only for WooCommerce products having a specific tag
I found a code that can add a shortcode below the short description of a WooCommerce product:
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description','ts_add_text_short_descr');
function ts_add_text_short_descr($description){
   $text = do_shortcode('[my-shortcode]');
  return $description . $text;
}

Then I tried to add that shortcode to the short description, only if a product has a specific product tag:
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'ts_add_text_short_descr');
function ts_add_text_short_descr($description) {
    global $product;   


    // Check if the product has a "VIP" tag
    $product_tags = wp_get_post_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_tag');
    $has_vip_tag = false;
    foreach ($product_tags as $tag) {
        if ($tag->slug === 'vip') {
            $has_vip_tag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If the product has the tag "VIP", add the shortcode
    if ($has_vip_tag) {
        $text = do_shortcode('[my-shortcode]');
        return $description . $text;
    } else {
        return $description;
    }
}

But it doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way to do it?

You can simplify your code by using WordPress has_term() conditional function, to check if a product has a specific product tag, like:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'add_text_to_short_description_conditionally' );
function add_text_to_short_description_conditionally( $description ){
    global $post;

    if ( has_term( array('vip'), 'product_tag' ) ) {
        $description .= do_shortcode('[my-shortcode]');
    }
    return $description;
}

It should work.
Note that WordPress has_term() conditional function accept term ID(s), slug(s) or name(s).

WooCommerce’s has_term() function, to check if a product has a
vip tag
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'ts_add_text_short_descr');
function ts_add_text_short_descr($description) {

    global $product;  

    // Check if the product has the tag "VIP" (you can replace 'vip' with your actual tag slug)
    if (has_term('vip', 'product_tag', $product->get_id())) {
        $text = do_shortcode('[my-shortcode]');
        return $text;
    }

    // Return the description without modification if no tag matches
    return $description;
}

